# Date Range in RazorSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ubuntu-10.04

How to display results with date range?

For example:
I want to show results for sept. 15, 2011 to oct. 20, 2011?

Thanks

Comment: For SQL-SERVER `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDate>='20110915' AND SomeDate<='20111029'`

Comment: I done that but the result is wrong. It's much lesser than the right result. Thanks. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date Range in RazorSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584925/date-range-in-razorsql)

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with RazorSQL and almost everything to do with the data that you're querying. Does the data set that you are querying have a date column that you can key off of? If so, you have two options.

1. Use a `where` clause in your SQL query to only bring back data from your source database that is within the range that you want.
2. Retrieve all of the data in a table and then use [RazorSQL's filter feature](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/filter_query_results.html) to whittle down the data.

Of course, from a performance perspective, the first option is the best.

Comment: I make a query in WHERE Clause and it goes like this: WHERE 
 OrdersHistory.OrderDate >= '2011-09-30' AND OrdersHistory.OrderDate < '2011-10-31'
    AND OrdersHistory.StatusFKID = 2 -- but the result is much lesser than the right result. what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will help you

```
select * from urtable where  cast (DATEPART(year, datatimeclm) as varchar(50))+'-'+cast (DATEPART(month, datatimeclm)as varchar(50))+'-'+ cast (DATEPART(day, datatimeclm)as varchar(50))  between '2011-09-15' and '2011-10-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server try this

```
DECLARE @tbl table(dtm datetime)

insert into @tbl 
values  ('20110914 00:59:00'),
        ('20110915'),
        ('20110915 05:10:00'),
        ('20110916 05:10:00'),
        ('20111029 05:10:00'),
        ('20111029'),
        ('20111030')

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
WHERE dtm>='20110915' AND dtm<'20111030'
```

To return date without time from a datetime value you can use this `CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar,@date,1),1)`

In SQL SERVER 2008 + you can use [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) data type in that case you could use `dtm<='20111029'`.